# how do i only get the integer to appear only in the final workbook

Tags: excel, vba, count, worksheet

Hi i have this code that counts the number of time "T" appears in the various workbooks where each workbook have around 10-12 sheets. the main objective is to have the final workbook get the the total number of times T appeared as it loops through the file.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wash_count As Integer

    'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
    myPath = myPath
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    myExtension = "*.xls*"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
    Do While myFile <> ""
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents

        For Each ws In wb.Sheets

            If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then

                For x = 5 To 74
                    If StrConv(ws.Cells(x, 2).Value, vbProperCase) = "Wash" And StrConv(ws.Cells(x, 4).Value, vbProperCase) = "T" Then 'added the StrConv to make sure you don't loose a case just because it was written in capital or lowercase letters
                        wash_count = wash_count + 1
                    End If
                Next x
             End If
        Next ws

        Sheets("Summary").Range("D6") = wash_count

        'Save and Close Workbook
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

        'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents

        'Get next file name
        myFile = Dir

    Loop

    'Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:

    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The problem now is that the previous workbooks with the sheets also named "Summary" gets the counter input inside it too.
right now the code gets the final count in the last workbook, but how do i avoid having it appear in the summary pages in the previous workbooks, i want to direct all the counts only to the final workbook.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim ColFiles As New Collection, i As Long

'...
'...
'...

'collect the files first
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
Do While myFile <> ""
    ColFiles.Add myPath & myFile
    myFile = Dir()
Loop

'now loop over the collection
For i = 1 To ColFiles.Count

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ColFiles(i))
    'count things in wb

    'is this the last file?
    If i = ColFiles.Count Then
        wb.Sheets("Summary").Range("D6") = wash_count
        wb.Close True  'save
    Else
        wb.Close False 'no save
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: HI is do i need to replace anything in my code to add this in? sorry im fairly new to VBA.